# Define React JSX code in database and then run it

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

I'd like to define my JSX code as a string, so that I can save it to a database, then load it and build the page with this code.

Can you recommend me a way to do this?

I don't want to use dangerouslysetinnerhtml, because it doesn't behave as a "real jsx components". Thank you.

Comment: My first question is : WHY

Comment: because i'm making a system where users can define their own code for a part of a page. and they can use certain components in it and to let them use some already defined jsx components would be ideal

Comment: Interesting use case. I had a similar problem for a project where the user constructs its UI via DND, but i just stored the component name used alongside the data the user entered and rendered the right component based on that.

Comment: Yes, my use case is the same - also defined via DND. Currently my entire page is stored in JSON format and then rendered based on that. But I hoped in some other possible solution as well (given that in for example PHP this is quite simple task)

Comment: Indeed, but yeah hopefully someone gets a better idea than i did back then :P!

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I'd like to let the user define the layout of a profile form whilst maintaining the logic to the service that gets/updates the data

Comment: I also looking for a solution to do that, but I think it's impossible to implement. But component need to action event and interact with DOM

Answer (score -1):

Since I see some people are still having this problem, I'm answering my question after three years - use https://mdxjs.com/ . It works both during the build and/or runtime.